# Postgresql - recover slave after out of sync with master using WAL

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication

I've setup a master / slave **Postgresql** *(13.4)* group, 1 master and 1 slave, using `WAL warm standby`.
*(refer: https://postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP)*

But, due to some reason, the slave is out of sync for a while, then due to the `WAL` file not exists anymore on the master, the slave can't sync anymore.

**Question:**
**A**. Is there anyway to recover the slave, to get back to sync ?
**B**. Or is there anyway to re-create the slave without stop the running master?

Either A or B is acceptable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there anyway to recover the slave, to get back to sync ?

No, unless you have archive WAL of all segments between current standby and primary server

> Or is there anyway to re-create the slave without stop the running master?

Just simple native [`pg_basebackup`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgbasebackup.html) command.

- stop current replica
- remove datadir (and tablespaces if any) on replica
- run pg_basebackup with appropriate oprions (typically I use `-R -X stream -c fast -P -U <replicationuser> -h source_addr`, `-R` is mandatory to start replica, not new primary)
- start DB and watch its logs

Comment: I've created another question above avoiding further slave out of sync, could also take a look if interested, thanks. Link: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303868/postgresql-increase-wal-retention-to-avoid-slave-go-out-of-sync-with-master

Comment: Ok, now slave recovered & working !