# Postgresql - increase WAL retention to avoid slave go out of sync with master

Tags: postgresql, replication, master-slave-replication

I've setup a master / slave `Postgresql` *(13.4)* group, 1 master and 1 slave, using WAL warm standby.
(refer: https://postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STANDBY-SERVER-SETUP)

The slave gone out of sync, and can't recover due to WAL not exists anymore on master, refer another question for details: [Postgresql - recover slave after out of sync with master using WAL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/303840)

Now, I'am re-doing the slave. There are **3.7T** data on master, and it's increasing pretty quickly, roughly **30Gb** per day ?

To avoid slave go out of sync again, I'm trying to increase the WAL retention.

Here is what I plan to do:

- `max_wal_size = 20Gb`
- `min_wal_size = 10GB`

**Questions:**

- **A-1**. Are the above param values proper?
- **A-2**. Does increasing these param has a bad side effect ?
- **A-3**. I only need to apply these 2 params to master, right?
- **B**. Is there more parameter that I should config?
- **C**. Any better way to avoid slave out of sync ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that won't help at all.

You have three alternative options:

- increase `wal_keep_size` to a big enough value

  That is a simple, but coarse solution, in that it makes the primary always retain a certain amount of WAL, regardless if it is too much or not enough (because the downtime is longer than expected).
- set a `restore_command` on the, so that it can use the WAL archive to catch up

  That may be the best option if you have a WAL archive.
- use a physical replication slot

  Such an object marks a certain position in the WAL stream and prevents the primary from discarding WAL that is still needed by the standby. While being an elegant solution, this bears the risk of breaking the primary if the standby stays down too long. Consequently, it is a good idea to monitor replication in this case and/or to set `max_slot_wal_keep_size` to put a cap on the amount of WAL retained on the primary.

Comment: Thanks, can you give a bit more details about the last 2 options, and can be 3 options be used together or just choose one?

Comment: Ok, let me try ` -c wal_keep_size=31000` first. 30Gb should be large enough.

Comment: I've changed the `wal_keep_size` on master, then create the slave again, now it's working again, thanks, I would check the other 2 options later.

Comment: Instead of using wal_keep_size=30GB, I suggest you to create a [replication slot](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS) and set [max_slot_wal_keep_size](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/runtime-config-replication.html#GUC-MAX-SLOT-WAL-KEEP-SIZE) to 40GB. With this, The Primary's WAL will keep disc size till 40GB and only if  it's necessary. You can also use slot without max_slot_wal_keep_size and monitor WAL folder size to prevent any "storage full" issue

Comment: @SahapAsci Thank you, I'll try it, you can also add / extend the comment as a separate answer, I think it's useful. And may describe more about the differences between the 2 solutions.

Comment: @user218867 Laurenz already did.

Comment: @SahapAsci I've check out `replication slot`, so its benefit is that only keep WAL as need thus save space & maybe a bit performance improvement, but if I can bear the space, it's almost identical to `wal_keep_size`, right?

Comment: By `physical replication slot`, you mean the thing mentioned in following link instead of an extra hardware, right? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/warm-standby.html#STREAMING-REPLICATION-SLOTS

Comment: The link is correct. The difference between a slot and `wal_keep_size` is that the former is always guaranteed to get it right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want more time of downtime before losing the replica server you can increase this parameter `wal_keep_segments = 3600` so you have more time to recover the replica server before the master server delete the old wal file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).